# Are inline style bad for screen readers?

Tags: css, xhtml, accessibility, screen-readers, w3c-validation

Example

```
<span style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffd700">Background color</span>
```

How screen reader handle inline css ? is there any other cons of inline CSS except css management?

Inline styles are valid also . i tested with W3C Validator and with XHTML 1.0 Strict doctype?

```
<p><span style="MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px">Left indent</span></p>
```

Comment: I thought screen readers would ignore all of the styling?

Comment: No. They read a combination of what is on the screen and what is in the DOM. Screen media stylesheets apply (e.g. `display: none` hides content from screen readers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How screen reader handle inline css ?

Same as any other CSS.

> is there any other cons of inline CSS except css management?

Just bandwidth related costs.

Comment: you mean 'style="MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px"' is not a problem for screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles are hard to manage and to override. And if you set colors and borders they may override your print stylesheet. I have seen yellow links in print previews …  clearly not the author’s intention but a very bad user experience.

Screenreaders honor only the `display` property, the don’t speak elements with `display:none`. It doesn’t matter where you declare it.